# Typescript + Vue + Svg Elements => Typisierung für inline SVG Element

Tags: vue.js, svg, types

Following situation I pass from parent Component a Function to Child which is seen on image 2. I want to declare the function inline like in image 1. I wrote a typedefinition like in image 3 and get the error like below written down.

I have no clue why this is the case.

return type is number and in errormessage it gives possibly undefined. Am I accessing the wrong function?

How can I access the correct one?

Happy for help

```
 <circle
          cx="350"
          cy="350"
          :r="getRingRadius(i, rings.length, 350)"
          fill="#ffffff"
  ></circle>
```

```
<script>
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    getRingRadius: {
      type: Function as PropType<getRingRadius>,
      required: false,
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

```
type getRingRadius = (r?: number, r1?: number, r2?: number) => number;
```

The Typescirpt error now is: "
let getRingRadius: getRingRadius | undefined
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)"

I just dont understand why?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is you have to set the Props on required on true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).